# How to send String via DataItem

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I can't connect my watchface with a handheld app. I want to send a simple text (on click button in the handheld) for understanding how it works. Unfortunately, I'm missing something because I have not any message in the watchface.

My onClickListener in the handheld MainActivity

```
sendDataItem.setOnClickListener {
            val putDataReq: PutDataRequest = PutDataMapRequest.create("/test").run {
                dataMap.putString("key", "TEST TEXT")
                asPutDataRequest()
            }
            val putDataTask: Task<DataItem> = dataClient.putDataItem(putDataReq)
        }
```

My override OnDataChanged method that (what I at least want to do) send data to my watchface

```
override fun onDataChanged(dataEvents: DataEventBuffer) {
            dataEvents.forEach { event ->
                // DataItem changed
                if (event.type == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
                    event.dataItem.also { item ->
                        if (item.uri.path.compareTo("/test") == 0) {
                            DataMapItem.fromDataItem(item).dataMap.apply {
                                weatherTemp = getString("key")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (event.type == DataEvent.TYPE_DELETED) {
                    // DataItem deleted
                }
            }
        }
```

I want a simple result. As soon I receive data I want to save it to weatherTemp var.

Comment: anything in logcat?

Comment: I'd just generally say that the Data API has quite a few moving parts to get right, and it's tough to tell from your snippets what might be wrong. One obvious thing is that if you're always sending the same `"TEST TEXT"`, you'll never get `onDataChanged`, because the data isn't *changing*. But you could have other issues as well. A good tactic might be to start with the API sample from Google and adapt its already-working code for your use case.

Comment: Ohh, I get the point of onDataChanged :D But now I have a problem with my app logic. I have an option list in a wearable. Is data item a good way to switch options from the handheld? 
Today I spend some time on google sample. I think that I don't get the sending data part. Can I send data in onClickListener? And one more thing, can I somehow check if the data item has been sent successfully (e.g. onDataRecived method)?

Comment: AFAIK, there's nothing like an "onDataReceived" event; we're at WearOS' mercy on this. And it's probably best to open a new question regarding `onClickListener`, with more details about your setup.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm really close to the solution. But I can't understand one thing. Can I somehow get the first received data? Because every next data is intercepting by onDataChanged, but first is lost. Thank you for your patience :D

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, sorry. No data should be "intercepted" by `onDataChanged`; all changes to data should be relied by the API to that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spend some time on this but finally, I get this working. In my watch face class I have onDataChange method that is receiving data item:

```
override fun onDataChanged(dataEvents: DataEventBuffer) {
            dataEvents.forEach { event ->
                if (event.type == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
                    val path = event.dataItem.uri.path
                    event.dataItem.also { item ->
                        if (path.compareTo("/testPath") == 0) {
                            DataMapItem.fromDataItem(item).dataMap.apply {
                               //I'm changing var that is printed on the watchface screen
                                testVar = getInt("key").toString()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (event.type == DataEvent.TYPE_DELETED) {
                    //DataItem deleted
                } else {
                    //Unknown data type event
                }
            }
        }
```

You cannot forget about:

```
 Wearable.getDataClient(applicationContext).addListener(this)
```

in your onCreate method.
I'm sending data item from my handheld activity on button press.

```
sendDataItem.setOnClickListener {
            putDataMapReq = PutDataMapRequest.create("/testPath")
            putDataMapReq.dataMap.putInt("key", testVar++)
            putDataReq = putDataMapReq.asPutDataRequest()
            putDataReq.setUrgent()
            putDataTask = Wearable.getDataClient(applicationContext).putDataItem(putDataReq)
        }
```

It's not perfect but at least it's working and I'm able to go ahead. If anything is unclear feel free to write the comment.